# Proper data insert from dynamically created input fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to insert data from below inputs to database. Whole `<div class="clone">` can be cloned with jquery and it also adds +1 to names, for example next created div will have inputs named name="npm[]1", name="apm[]1" etc. 
 `<div class="list" id="sub">` part list subcategories of shops that can be checked (shop can have multiple subcategories) and they also get +1 on names. Is it ok like that?

```
<div class="clone">
    <label>Shop name</label><input type="text" name="npm[]0" id="npm" required>
    <label>Address</label><input type="text" name="apm[]0" id="apm" required>
    <label>City</label><input type="text" name="mipm[]0" id="mipm" required>
    <label>Working hours</label><input type="text" name="rv[]0" id="rv" required>
    <label>Tel</label><input type="text" name="ktf[]0" id="ktf" required>
    <label>Mob</label><input type="text" name="ktm[]0" id="ktm" required>
    <label>E-mail</label><input type="text" name="kea[]0" id="kea" required>
    <label>Contact person</label><input type="text" name="ipko[]0" id="ipko" required>

    <a id="select" class="ctpct">Select shop subcategory</a>
      <div class="list" id="sub">
        <?php
         $a="select a.id,a.cat,b.x,b.subcat,b.cat_id from cat a
            inner join
                subcat b
                    on a.id = b.cat_id
                        where b.cat_id !=1
                            order by a.id";

         $res = mysql_query($a) or die(mysql_error());

         $cat = '';

         while ($re = mysql_fetch_array($res))
         {
          if( $cat === '' )
           {
             $cat = $re["cat"];
             echo "<div class='catdis'>";
             echo "<h2>$cat</h2>";
           }
          elseif( $cat !== $re["cat"] )
           {
             $cat = $re["cat"];
             echo "</div>";
             echo "<div class='catdis'>";
             echo "<h2>$cat</h2>";
           }

           $subcat= $re["subcat"];
           $id= $re["x"];

           echo "<input type='checkbox' name='subcat[]0' value='$id'> $subcat<br />";

         }

       ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

PHP part:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

$query2 = "INSERT INTO shops(n, a, c, wh, tel, mob, mail, con) VALUES ('$values')";
$rs2=mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Now, php part that i have prints this "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1", it may be because under that clone div i have few more inputs, normal ones. 
 I'am php newbie so can you please help me with this. I need it to insert data for every shop from input 'Shop name' to 'Contact person' in table 'shops' and selected subcategories in table 'shop_subcat' with subcategory_id and shop_id 
 Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the input fields names like `name="apm[]"`. PHP treats names that end with `[]` specially, it turns all the inputs into an array. So you can do:

```
foreach ($_POST['apm'] as $apm) {
    ...
}
```

to process all those inputs.

Your `name="apm[]0"` doesn't follow this pattern, so it doesn't work.

Also, remove the `id` attributes from your inputs. IDs are required to be unique, and when you clone the DIV you're creating duplicates.

To solve the SQL error, you need to fix your query. You list 7 columns to insert into, so you have to provide 7 values.

```
$input_count = count($_POST['npm']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $input_count; $i++) {
    $n = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['npm'][$i]);
    $a = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['apm'][$i]);
    // Repeat above pattern for all the other inputs
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO shops(n, a, c, wh, tel, mob, mail, con) 
               VALUES ('$n', '$a', '$c', '$wh', '$mob', '$mail', '$con')";
    $rs2=mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: thank you, but am still getting that column count error. i renamed  input fields. does everything else in php part is same except foreach?

Comment: That's a SQL error. You list 7 columns to insert into, but you only have one value in `VALUES ('$values')`.

Comment: do i need to name that array somehow to get all values or?

Comment: it works, thank you. ill try do it for subcategories